# If cell value has letters and numbers, delete row

Tags: vba, excel

please tell me what is the filter to check if a cell contains letters and numbers or the cell contains only  letters ? If contains only numbers it must pass to the next cell.  I have been searching but the only results are if cell contains certain value or text but i cant find an example form my problem.

```
    With ActiveSheet
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "e")
          If .Value = " cell has letters AND numbers OR just letters " Then
            .EntireRow.Delete  
          End With
        Next Lrow
    End With
```

Comment: How about if the cell is empty ??

Comment: i got that cover :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before:

[image]

I would examine each character:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim KillMe As Boolean, CH As String
    With ActiveSheet
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
            KillMe = False
            With .Cells(Lrow, "e")
                For i = 1 To Len(.Value)
                    CH = Mid(.Value, i, 1)
                    If CH Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then KillMe = True
                Next i
                If KillMe Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        Next Lrow
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note:**

This ignores punctuation and special characters.  It looks for **letters only.**

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a WorksheetFunction like this:

```
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
...
If Application.Evaluate("=Count(Find({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}," & _ 
.Address & ")) > 0") Then    
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the formatting of the cell you could be able to use

`With ActiveSheet
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "e")
          If worksheetfunction.IsText(.Value) Then
            .EntireRow.Delete

          End With
    Next Lrow
End With`

Comment: `ISTEXT()` returns `TRUE` if there is both a number and a letter.

Comment: Sorry I thought that was what op was after

Comment: @maxhob17 Looks like I misunderstood, too. :)